# load page with message (asp.net)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

the query is working but afer deleting i got "no records found message" so i cant see other subcategories. but when i return page again i can see other subcategories. how can i this fix

[No records found message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mTWW.jpg)

```
DataTable dtCategory = system.GetDataTable(@"Select * from TBLCATEGORIES 
  where SubCategoryID=" + CategoryID);
if (dtCategory.Rows.Count > 0)
{
  rpCategory.DataSource = dtCategory;
  rpCategory.DataBind();
}
else
{
  NoRecordsFound.Visible = true;
}

  if (Process == "Delete")
{
    DataTable dtProducts = system.GetDataTable("Select COALESCE(COUNT(1),0) as TOTAL from TBLPRODUCTS where CategoryID = " + CategoryID);
    if (dtProducts.Rows[0]["TOTAL"].ToString() == "0")
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("data source=localhost;initial catalog=Shqiptar; Integrated Security=SSPI;");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from TBLCATEGORIES where CategoryID=" +  Request.QueryString["CategoryID"] );

        try {
             cnn.Open();
             cmd.Connection=cnn;
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   

        }

        catch(Exception ex) {
             lblMsg.Text = ex.Message;
        }

        finally {  
             cnn.Close(); 
             DeleteMsg.Visible = true;
        }
 }
        else  {
           InfoMsg.Visible=true;
        }
```

Comment: After delete operation you need to rebind your grid

Comment: if this code binds data then  this is right after delete operation

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: why? how can rebind data pls help me.

Comment: Why this code is vulnerable to SQL injection ? Because the query is build with string concatenation, moreover with query string arguments. A first level of sql injection protection is to pass sql parameters with SQLServerParameter objects, like cms.Parameters.Add(new SQLServerParameter("@PARAM1","value")).

Comment: can u help me pls i cant do that...:(

Comment: how can i fix this? the query can be delete subcategory but after delete opertaion i dont know how to rebind data?